# Bookshelf.js, query on related table

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have a model similar to the following:

```
var ScholarlyPaper = Bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName: 'papers',

  paragraphs: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Paragraph).through(Section);
  },

  sections: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Section);
  }

});

var Section = Bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName: 'sections',

  paragraphs: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Paragraph);
  }

  scholarlyPaper: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(ScholarlyPaper);
  }

});

var Paragraph = Bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName: 'paragraphs',

  section: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Section);
  },

  scholarlyPaper: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(ScholarlyPaper).through(Section);
  },

  author: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Author);
  }

});

var Author = Bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName: 'authors',

  paragraphs: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Paragraph);
  }

});
```

**Using Bookshelf.js, given a scholarlyPaper id and author id, how can I get all of the sections in the paper that the author did not write a single paragraph in?**

The particular challenge I am facing is that there is no way that I am aware of to add a where clause on a related table (e.g 'where paragraphs.author_id != author_id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function(authorId, paperId, success, failure) {
  new ScholarlyPaper({id: paperId}).load({sections: function(qb) {
    qb.whereNotExists(function() {
      this.from('paragraph')
        .whereRaw('paragraph.section = section.id')
        .where('paragraph.author_id', '=', authorId);
    });
  }}).then(function(paper) {
    success(paper.related('section'));
  }, failure);
};
```

Comment: You might want to do .where('paragraph.author_id', authorId) as opposed to whereRaw there so your parameter is bound.

Comment: Hi, I know its old answer. But When I try the above. I am getting the below compilation error. Could anyone help. I am using this with typescript    Argument of type '{ sections: (qb: any) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[]'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'sections' does not exist in type 'string | string[]'.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
new ScholarlyPaper({id: 1}).load({paragraphs: function(qb) {
  qb.where('paragraphs.author_id', '!=', author_id);
}}).then(function(paper) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(paper.related('paragraphs')));
});
```

Comment: This was not quite what I needed but it helped me get to a solution. So thank you. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [bookshelf-eloquent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bookshelf-eloquent) extension. The whereHas() and with() functions are probably what you are looking for. Your function would look something like this:

```
async function(authorId, paperId) {
    return await ScholarlyPaper.where('id', paperId)
        .with('sections', (q) {
            // Filter out sections in the paper that the author did not write a single paragraph in.
            q.whereHas('paragraphs', (q) => {
                q.where('author_id', authorId);
            }, '<=', 0);
        }).first();
}
```